# Programmatically create a btrfs file system whose root directory has a specific owner

Tags: linux, btrfs

### Background

I have a test script that creates and destroys file systems on the fly, used in a suite of performance tests.

To avoid running the script as root, I have a disk device `/dev/testdisk` that is owned by a specific user `testuser`, along with a suitable entry in `/etc/fstab`:

```
$ ls -l /dev/testdisk
crw-rw---- 1 testuser testuser 21, 1 Jun 25 12:34 /dev/testdisk
$ grep testdisk /etc/fstab
/dev/testdisk /mnt/testdisk auto noauto,user,rw 0 0
```

This allows the disk to be mounted and unmounted by a normal user.

### Question

I'd like my script (which runs as `testuser`) to programmatically create a **btrfs** file system on `/dev/testdisk` such that the root directory is owned by `testuser`:

```
$ mount /dev/testdisk /mnt/testdisk
$ ls -la /mnt/testdisk
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 testuser  testuser   4096 Jun 25 15:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root      root       4096 Jun 23 17:41 ..
drwx------ 2 root      root      16384 Jun 25 15:15 lost+found
```

Can this be done without running the script as root, and without resorting to privilege escalation (use of `sudo`) within the script?

### Comparison to other file systems

With ext{2,3,4} it's possible to create a filesystem whose root directory is owned by the current user, with the following command:

```
mkfs.ext{2,3,4} -F -E root_owner /dev/testdisk
```

### Workarounds I'd like to avoid (if possible)

I'm aware that I can use the `btrfs-convert` tool to convert an existing (possibly empty) ext{2,3,4} file system to btrfs format. I *could* use this workaround in my script (by first creating an ext4 filesystem and then immediately converting it to brtfs) but I'd rather avoid it if there's a way to create the btrfs file system directly.

Comment: You could create a small btrfs filesystem, manually change the root owner (use `sudo` here), and then use it as template: `dd` to the device and grow it to fill the device with `btrfs filesystem resize`. If the device is small enoughyou can even go with creating the template the same size.

Comment: @rodrigo One must be careful with block-level copies of btrfs filesystems, because having two btrfs devices with the same UUID available to the kernel [can lead to filesystem corruption](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas).